# Emailer going responsive automatically

Tags: html, mailer

I want to send a html emailer. I have coded using tables. I havent made it responsive. But when I upload it in any emailer client like groupmail or campaign monitor and send an email. Its converting it to responsive design. When i see it in mobile it is stacked one upon another and its responsive.

However I don't want it to be responsive. I want the same output I get on desktop..How do i do it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Shantiniketans</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,400italic">    
<body>    
<table border="0" width="600" background="images/bg.jpg">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" width="600">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#4886bb; text-align:center">Thank you for your enquiry about SHANTINIKETAN ALTAIR at magicbricks.com</p></td></tr></tbody></table>                
      <table border="0" width="606">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img alt="" src="images/elevation.jpg" width="606" 
            height="418"></td></tr></tbody></table>                
      <table style="margin-top: -3px; margin-left: 2px" border="0" width="607"  background="images/blue_bg.jpg">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;  font-family: 'Lato';  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);  line-height: 1.2;  text-align: center;">SHANTINIKETAN ALTAIR, a project of smart value homes now nearing 
            completion, is located just 2.2 kms from Kelambakkam junction on OMR 
            – the IT Highway and the growth corridor of Chennai. Which means, 
            the potential for capital appreciation in the near future is 
            high.</p></td></tr></tbody></table>
      <table style="margin-top: 13px" border="0" width="600" height="180">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:304px; height:212px; float:left;">
            <h4 style="font-size: 33px;  font-family: 'Lato';  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);  line-height: 0.727;  text-align: left;  font-weight:100; padding: 0px;  margin: 4px;">Altair</h4>
            <p style="  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.473;
  text-align: justify;width:274px;
  float: left;">SHaNTINIKETaN aLTaIR offers you a choice of 1, 2 and 3 BHK 
            apartments at an all inclusive rate of Rs. 3,425/- per sq. ft. 
            (inclusive of all taxes, registration, electricity and water, 
            infrastructure development charges and electrical fittings, etc.) 
            with a promise of delivery within one month. What’s more, we even 
            have an assured Rental IncomeScheme.Come and visit our site, inspect 
            the model flat as well as the completed flats.</p></td>
          <td style="width:287px; height:142px; float:left;">
            <h4 style="font-size: 33px;  font-family: 'Lato';  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);  line-height: 0.727;  text-align: left;  font-weight:100; padding: 0px;  margin: 4px;">Hightlights</h4>
            <table style="margin-top: 16px" border="0" width="275">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img alt="" src="images/highlights.jpg" width="277" height="96"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>




      <table style="text-align:center" border="0" width="600" height="150">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="http://www.shantiniketans.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/view_web.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></td>
          <td><a href="http://www.shantiniketans.com/contact.html" 
            target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/contact_us.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></td>
          <td><a 
            href="http://www.shantiniketans.com/images/Shantiniketan_altair.pdf" 
            target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/download_broc.jpg"             width="100" height="100"></a></td></tr></tbody></table>




      <table style="margin-left: -2px" border="0" width="607">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center; margin-left: 2px"><img alt="" src="images/logo.jpg" width="607" 
height="128"></td></tr></tbody></table>



      <table style="background: #3670a2" border="0" width="607">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style=" font-size: 21px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;">Give us a Call at +91-98846   56561/63/64</p></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>



            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about sending emails your self, use mail chimp or other tool for this task.

You will always have this type of problems and other problem can be that your emails can be considered as spam.